# Pandas time series Classification issue

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to classify a variable [Time] as datetime, after manipulating original date. Issue is with the 6th line of code, throwing the error: "TypeError:  is not convertible to datetime"

Original Local Time column contains:

```
03.01.2016 17:00:00.000 GMT-0500
```

---

```
gu['Local time']=gu['Local time'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('GMT-0500'))
gu['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(gu['Local time'])

gu['Date']=gu['DateTime'].dt.date
gu['Date']=pd.to_datetime(gu['Date'])

gu['Time']=gu['DateTime'].dt.time
gu['Time']=pd.to_datetime(gu['Time'])

print (gu.info())
```

Comment: Hi  BDNFX welcome on SO, do you mind to have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve)? Then the title is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format argument to specify the datetime format

```
gu['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(gu['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

See the documentation for details.

[pandas.to_datetime documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: If you want to convert back to datetime you cannot get rid of the date part.